# how to insert data using pdo in sql server using php?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I inserting data using pdo statement , it throw fallowing exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: An error occurred translating string for input param 11 to 
UCS-2: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte 
code page.
```

my input param 11 value like this:  `abc, 84*, xxx 750 yy. ~ $114.0000 , I thought exception with '*' in it's value .`

how to solve this exception ,can any one help me?

my insert pdo statement format like as fallow:

```
$insert2 =$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename(column1, column2, column3, 
column4, column5, column6, column7, column8, column9, column10, column11, 
column12) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$insert2->execute(array($value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5,$value6,
$value7,$value8,$value9,$value10,$value11,$value12));
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the character format u r using? is it : array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")

Comment: Please can you post the block of code around where this is happening? The problem looks like it's to do with an input value but it might help to see the code too.

Comment: pundit it is sql server database,not the mysql database